# JavaScript SVG Matrix scaleY ignored

Tags: svg, matrix, scale

I'm trying to scale a SVG element using scale() method from matrix, but scaleY parameter is ignored.

I expect the element to scale 4 times on Y axis, but second parameter to scale is ignored.
Am I doing something wrong?

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#test');
var transformList = elem.transform.baseVal,
    transform = transformList.getItem(0),
    matrix = transform.matrix;

transform.setMatrix(matrix.scale(1.1, 4));

transformList.replaceItem(transform, 0);
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect width="100" height="100" id="test" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the SVG specification scale takes a single argument. You need [scaleNonUniform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix)...

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#test');
var transformList = elem.transform.baseVal,
    transform = transformList.getItem(0),
    matrix = transform.matrix;

transform.setMatrix(matrix.scaleNonUniform(1.1, 4));

transformList.replaceItem(transform, 0);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect width="100" height="100" id="test" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, but scaleNonUniform seems to be deprecated according to MDN. I will look future on this, for now this seems to be OK.

Comment: I guess MDN needs to update its documentation then to undeprecate this.

Comment: OK, thanks, that will be good, as I won't have to look for other solutions..